# Exact Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

```
Revised
```

I'm trying to solve this exact differential equation

$$(e^x\sin(y)-3x^2)\,dx+(e^x\cos(y)+\frac{y^\frac{-2}{3}}{3})\,dy=0$$

Then to verify if is an exact differential equation:

$$\frac{\partial(e^x\sin(y)-3x^2)}{\partial y} = e^x\cos(y)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial(e^x\cos(y)+\frac{y^\frac{-2}{3}}3)}{\partial x}) = e^x\cos(y)$$

then

$$f(x,y) = \int e^x\sin(y)-3x^2 \, dx = e^x\cos(y)-x^3$$

adding the integration "constant":

$$e^x\cos(y)-x^3+g(y)$$

then

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=e^x\cos(y)+g'(y)=e^x\cos(y)+\frac{y^\frac{-2}{3}}{3}$$

then

$$g'(y)=e^x\cos(y)-e^x\cos(y)+\frac{y^\frac{-2}{3}}{3}$$

and

$$ g'(y)=\frac{y^\frac{-2}{3}}{3}  \Rightarrow g(y)=\int \frac{y^\frac{-2}{3}}{3} \, dy = y^\frac{1}{3}+c$$

Solution

$$f(x,y)=e^x\cos(y)-x^3+y^\frac{1}{3}+c$$

```
Just a fews doubts
```

I saw in some examples when you integrate the $dx$ becomes $x$, that's why I thought this was result of the integration:

$$f(x,y) = \int(e^x\sin(y)-3x^2)\,dx = e^x\cos(y)-x^3x = e^x\cos(y)-x^4 $$

You can check the original problem in ([source](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=-P76slq9Kf8C&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq#v=onepage&q&f=false)) go to problem 12 (page 66)

Comment: Assuming the rest of your work is right,  from the second to last equation to the last, you should just have $g'(y)=\frac 1 3 y^{-\frac 2 3}$

Comment: First mistake: $f(x,y)=e^x\cos y-x^3+g(x,y)$, not $f(x,y)=e^x\cos y-x^4+g(x,y)$. Second mistake: $g'(y)=\frac13y^{-2/3}$, not what you write. Final result: $f(x,y)=e^x\cos y-x^3+y^{1/3}+C$.